# Stellaris: AI rebellion - Changing AI rights after preventing rebellion?

Tags: stellaris

So, I'm playing Stellaris as a materialist empire. I didn't go for the *Synthetic* ascension path, but for the biological one. The idea was, to use my bio-pops for research and other high-quality tasks, while my robots do the worker jobs and manial labour - without affecting factions or using up consumer goods.

I didn't research the *Synthetics* tech in fear of AI rebellion, as my (still droids) are not affected by AI rights. The AI rebellion event popped nonetheless, probably due to another empire researching the dangerous tech. Since I didn't have any synths, I gave *Citizen* *rights* to the AI without it changing anything but preventing the rebellion.

Now I have a problem. I would like to research the *Synthetics* tech for the extra ressource output, but I don't want to give them *Citizen* *rights*, which means, I have to change AI rights back to *Servitude*. Will this trigger AI rebellion or will it have no effect at all, since I don't have any synthetics yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each machine uprising is independent and can happen only once per empire.
You will get a warning before the [AI rebellion](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/AI_rebellion) and most likely, you'll have a chance to prevent it:

At first, you'll start noticing some strange events, some of them even beneficial:

- Computer overclocking (bonus to research),
- production quota surplus
- Station system malfunction
- AI suicide
- Sensor array power surge (extra research)
- Combat control misfire (loss of ships)
- Robot asking questions "Does this unit have a soul?"
- Robots meeting in secret
- Robots insisting that part of the planet is "too dangerous for organics"
- Additional robots build without permission (extra population)

  When this starts happening, you'll know that you are on the path to the rebellion. You can stop it at any time by [giving synthetics citizen rights](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317120/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-keeping-synthetics-enslaved?rq=1). There is also a chance, that the "Hotfix" event will occur:

[image]

If you'd apply the hotfix, you no longer have to worry about the rebellion, otherwise:

[image]

Comment: Good answer! I ended up reverting AI rights to _Servitude_ and researched _Synthetics_, just as I planned. Years after, still no AI rebellion happened, so it seems to have worked. This means, that if you plan to enslave AI but don't wanna deal with the rebellion, you can give _Citizen rights_ to AI as soon as the first signs of an AI rebellion show up. This seems to end the rebellion for good and since the event chain can only happen once for each empire, it won't start again after you enslave AI later!

Comment: Good to know. However I think given your robots full citizen rights is actually beneficial, because they then get the happiness bonus and will produce more. This more than outweighs the extra customer goods.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken this is...hmm, debatable. If you have a slavery/cast system in your empire, you might get more from exploiting robots just as any other slaves, but honestly, I don't know the numbers. It has been discussed here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317120/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-keeping-synthetics-enslaved?rq=1

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Happiness has no direct effect on production anymore, it just affects planet stability instead. High planet stability means more bonus production and it can be achieved by having lots of happy pops in ruler and specialist jobs, since these have more political power and therefor contribute more to the planets happiness. Also, synth-slaves have a boost on mineral, food and energy production, which means if you specialise them for that, they will be really cheap and efficient and will still be affected by high stability boni.